# Sylius installation error step 3 of 4 while creating administrator

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sylius

while installing Sylius I get an error. Do you have any solutions?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably asking for an email, did you input it?

Comment: The problem is, it did not ask me for anything :/

Comment: Did you ran it with `--no-interaction`?

Comment: Thank you Victor! It works now!!! :) Let me hug you haha